# How to upload an app without having landscape mode through AppLoader?

Tags: xcode8, uiinterfaceorientation, ios-universal-app

I am trying to upload an Universal app which supports only Portrait mode. But while uploading the package through AppLoader, it's want me to enable Landscape mode. But I don't want to support Landscape mode in my Application. Please have a look the following image. How to upload an app without having landscape mode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer but for someone else who is still looking for answers.

Go to **Project Navigator >** **General Tab >** Choose Device Orientation to portrait mode only or whatever you designed.

Secondly, If you are targeting both then use constraints and **UIStackView** or for large changes use different storyboards.

Thanks for reading it.